# Elastic search find size of index for a subset of results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to find the disk size occupied by a set of records in an index specified by a query.
I am able to get the total size using the _stats API.

While getting count I can provide a filter to get count of records that match it.

localhost:9200/index/_count -- total no. of records

localhost:9200/index/_count?q=key:value -- no. of records that match key==value

I'm looking for something like above to get the size of records where key==value.

Thanks